# Display data vertical asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I display data from my database(1,2,3,4) in a web page. I create the connetction with database and the command and i put the numbers in a label like that:

```
string temp1 = "";
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                temp1 += reader["IDq"].ToString();}
```

lbl_test1.Text = temp1;

and then i write it like that in aspx file :

```
<table>
<tr>
       <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_test1" runat="server"></asp:Label> </td>
           
            </tr><.table>
```

The problem is that it appear in web page like: 1234567
How can i do to appear like :

1

2

3

4

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need send list of values to View

in Controller file:

```
var idList = new List<string>();

while(reader.Read())
{
   stringIdList.Add(reader["IDq"].ToString());
}
ViewBag.IdList = idList;
```

aspx file:

```
<table>
   @foreach (var id in ViewBag.IdList)
   {
      <tr>
         <td><label>@id</label></td>
      </tr>
   }
</table>
```